# problem with archimesh roof

Tags: archimesh-add-on

Okay so I am designing a barn for a guy in my town, and I was trying to put the roof on, but when I selected the roof option, I quickly found out there were no options to costuming said roof, like there is for the walls, doors, and windows. am I missing something? or was is it supposed to be like this? and if so, what do I do now?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's a tutorial on that addon which includes a section on creating the roof [here](https://youtu.be/xMVWAaKfWXs?t=1255) which might help. (I've never used that addon myself so have no personal experience of using it.)

Comment: thank you so much, very helpful!!